# Feasible approach for TCP/IP connections in modem-agnostic manner?

Tags: at-command, gprs

We have been searching a lot on the internet, and every modem-manufacturer seems to have a different set of AT-commands for establishing TCP/IP sockets.

We were wondering if there is a modem-agnostic way to do this (using only the standard Hayes AT commands)?

We are thinking of following ::

a)
Connect the micro-controller with the modem through a vanilla serial UART connection.

b)
Bring the modem into "CONNECT" state, by firing the standard Hayes AT commands through the UART. Thereafter, the modem would be in data-mode.

c)
Within our application, we wrap all our payload with the Layer4 (TCP) and Layer3 (IP) headers (using open-source frameworks like lwIP), and then send these packets via UART to the modem (all while the modem is in data-mode). Similarly, we receive the packets from the modem (while still in data-mode) via UART to the micro-controller, and then use lwIP to strip the IP and TCP headers.

This way, we are not dependent on the non-standard extended AT-commands (different for each vendor).

Would this approach handle any modem? Or there is some inherent drawback?

Comment: "The Hayes Standard"  is of course not a formal standard, and Hayes modems predate GPRS by about two decades. How do you expect a 1200 baud POTS modem to support a standard that won't be invented in its lifetime?

Comment: @MSalters, haha .. let me re-phrase my question in this way ::  Would the approach work fine on all the GPRS modems (irrespective of whether or not the modems carry the embedded TCP/IP stack in themselves) ?